# Lithium PHP framework - query parameters not passed to model ?

Tags: php, parameters, model, frameworks, lithium

I work on a project, built with Lithium PHP framework and some other libraries like the "Resource" library. And so - I have a controller, that starts with:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers\admin;

class Prices extends Base {

  protected $_parameters = array(
    'index' => array(

      'prices' => array(
        'required' => false,
        'call'     => array(
          'all',
          'conditions' => array(
            'advertiser' => 'query:advertiser'
          )
        )
      )

    )
  );
```

And the problem is that when I open the url with $_GET parameter `advertiser` - it is not passed to the model.

BUT - if I hardcode the advertiser ID like this:

```
  ...
  'prices' => array(
    'required' => false,
    'call'     => array(
      'all',
      'conditions' => array(
        'advertiser' => '123'
      )
    )
  )
```

and then I get the prices only for this advertiser - as I should.

What could be wrong? ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup filter to achieve that, also natebele promised it will refactor li3_resources library to be more flexible:
Here is the link to the filter: https://gist.github.com/nateabele/5667381
It also includes simple use case in code comments if you need one.